# I want Pidgin links opened in Chromium not in Firefox

Tags: 13.04, chromium, default-programs, pidgin

When I attempt to open a link in Pidgin it opens the link with Firefox. I prefer Chromium. I have Chromium set as the default application in the System Settings folder, but Firefox still opens the links. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you run `xdg-open 'http://askubuntu.com/'` in the terminal, which browser opens? Feel free to edit your question to add details like this.

Answer (score 9):

I have Pidgin 2.10.7 (libpurple 2.10.7) from the software center. I click on `Tools`, `Preferences` and then on `Browser`.

[image: Pidgin Browser Preferences]

Does that not help you?

If it doesn't, try

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

You should see a list of GUI-based browsers that your system detects. Then follow the on-screen instructions to choose the browser you want.

```
[11:03 AM] ~ $ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
[sudo] password for vasa1: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                    Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/google-chrome   150       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/google-chrome   150       manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/xombrero        50        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```